# Need to understand JQuery load on click on a link flow and mistakes in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make my 10 pages static website dynamic so that everytime i don't need to design every page as the same home page. I have tried few jquery statements to load data into div on click of a link.

I have tried the following code and it didn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
          $("#div1").load("demo.txt");
        });
        $("#link").click(function() {
          $("#div1").load("demo.txt");
        });
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="div1">
      <h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
    <button>Get External Content</button>
    <br>
    <br> <a href="#" id="link">click here</a> </body>

</html>
```

I have got this from W3School's online Tryit editer. It works fine there but not in my local webpage on my machine. Can I get an explanation what is happening and what I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: Are you running a local webserver?  `.load()` (or any other XHR requests) won't work on `file://` urls.

Comment: Console shows the following error:                                                                                                 jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Profiles/ggagandeep/Desktop/TP/demo_test.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: I am using a simple text editer notepad++ and running the webpage on chrome. Not running on a webserver (please let me know if i need to install one).